# How can I use JQuery to retrieve the list of all the tags having a specific class setted and then remove the content from these tags?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I am not yet so into JavaScript and JQuery and I have the following problem.

Into an HTML page I have some  tag that contain some content (the numer of the  tag are not fixed and can change at runtime, something like this:

```
<section id="mainSection" class="com__section com__section--text">
    .........................................................
    .........................................................
    MAIN SECTION CONTENT
    .........................................................
    .........................................................
</content>

<section class="com__section com__section--text functionSection">
    <h1 class="animate slideInRight" ">SECTION 1</h1>
    .........................................................
    .........................................................
</section>

<section class="com__section com__section--text functionSection">
    .........................................................
    .........................................................
    <h1 class="animate slideInRight" ">SECTION 2</h1>
    .........................................................
    .........................................................
</section>
```

As you can see the first  tag have the **id="mainSection"** and it is always present in the page. The other instead have the **class="functionSection"** setted.

My problem is that I have to use JQuery to retrieve the list of all the  having the **class="functionSection"** setted and remove all the content inside these sections.

How can I use JQuery to retrieve all the section having this **functionSection** class and remove theirs content? (The section tags must remain in my HTML but have to be empty).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple! Remove the `html` content

```
$('.functionSection').html("");
```

Do you want bulletproof? Iterate all elements.

```
$('.functionSection').each(function() {
   $(this).html("");
});
```

Comment: Or just `.empty()`

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude what do you exactly mean with "bulletproof"?

Comment: If you are scared with multiple elements, maybe the first syntax can cause misunderstanding (it seems one element, really jQuery make the iteration internally). The second syntax you can see in first sight that there are possible multiple elements and iterate through all of them

Answer (score 1):

`$('.functionSection').html('');` will remove all of the html content from any tag with the class functionSection -- was there anything else you wanted it to do?